# Remove duplicates from JavaScript Array of Objects based on Key

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object as shown below

```
var fileList = [
{
    identifier: "auto-1",
    file: "mp.mp3"
},
{
    identifier: "auto-2",
    file: "ss.mp3"
},
{
    identifier: "auto-3",
    file: "mj.mp3"
},
{
    identifier: "type1",
    file: "ss.mp3"
},
{
    identifier: "type2",
    file: "sc.mp3"
},
{
    identifier: "tyep3",
    file: "mj.mp3"
}
]
```

I'm trying to remove elements from the array. If the `identifier` includes the text `auto`, I want to remove the element if that Object's `file` matches a `file` which is included in the Objects with the identifiers `type1` or `type2` or `type3`. The Identifier will be unique.

**Expected output**:

```
[
{
    identifier: "auto-1",
    file: "mp.mp3"
},
{
    identifier: "type1",
    file: "ss.mp3"
},
{
    identifier: "type2",
    file: "sc.mp3"
},
{
    identifier: "tyep3",
    file: "mj.mp3"
}
]
```

I have tried the below code snippet but that is getting unique values by eliminating objects from identifiers `type1`, `type2`,...etc.

```
_.uniq(fileList ,function(item){ return item.file + item.identifier; })
```

Comment: Your question in not clear, please reformulate. I didn't understand what you need.

Comment: please explain clearly of what exactly ur looking for

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira can you please let me know what exactly you are looking for its a straight forward one, here i specified the input object and output object

Comment: @Geeky i specified that in expected output

Comment: See my answer ... Let me know if that helps

Comment: You need to specify if the filenames you want to match are *only* in Objects with `identifier`: `type1`, `type2`, and `type3`, or if it is `type<number>`. Alternately, should any `identifier` that does not contain `auto` be considered as containing a filename to exclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the little that i understand. 
you can use reduce for this

check the code snippet

```js
var fileList = [{
    identifier: "auto-1",
    file: "mp.mp3"
  },
  {
    identifier: "auto-2",
    file: "ss.mp3"
  },
  {
    identifier: "auto-3",
    file: "mj.mp3"
  },
  {
    identifier: "type1",
    file: "ss.mp3"
  },
  {
    identifier: "type2",
    file: "squirrel-chatter.mp3"
  },
  {
    identifier: "type3",
    file: "mj.mp3"
  }
]
var fileList2 = [{
  identifier: "auto-1",
  file: "mp.mp3"
}, {
  identifier: "type1",
  file: "mp.mp3"
}]

var result;

result = fileList2.reduce(function callback(result, key, index, keysArray) {
  debugger;
  let indx = result.findIndex((item) => item.file === key.file)
  if (indx > -1) {
    result[indx].identifier = (key.identifier.includes("type")) ? key.identifier : result[indx].identifier
  } else {
    result.push(key)
  }
  return result
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: appreciate for the quick response @Geeky, this is returning the same list

Comment: no the filtered ouput is in the result...what do u mean by same list?

Comment: sorry you are absolutely correct, can we do that without hardcoding `(key.identifier.includes("type"))` because it will contain a different value like 'sports', 'movies', 'university' etc... instead of using 'type' can we use 'auto' because auto will be for sure there

Comment: i managed to get that Thank you so much

Comment: actually this is failing when the first object has a duplicate value for 'file' for example for the below case                                                                 `var fileList = [
    {
        identifier: "auto-1",
        file: "mp.mp3"
    },
    {
        identifier: "type1",
        file: "mp.mp3"
    }
    ] `

Comment: yaa just change the index to be greater than -1, in my code it is looking for >0..changing that should solve your issue...check the code snippet

Comment: awesome i did not noticed that, thanks @Geeky

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your criterion for uniqueness: your explanation and expected output seem to conflict.

But at the very least, try `_.uniqBy` which accepts a iteratee function. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy

`_.uniq` does not, which may be your problem.